# Como ajustar o splash usando Constraints no Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, resolução-de-tela, xib

No Xcode 6 vem um arquivo de formato .xib que serve como a splash screen padrão do App.

Inseri uma imagem, usando *UIImageView* e um texto usando *UILabel* mas a posição da imagem e da *label* mudam conforme o tamanho da tela do dispositivo.

Devo configurar o Constraints para manter tudo na mesma posição em telas diferentes ou existe outra alternativa?

Comment: Se estiver usando *autolayout* o uso de constraints é sempre necessário. A outra alternativa é mesmo usar a *LaunchImage*, uma imagem para cada tipo de tela como era antes do Xcode 6.

Comment: Sim, mas estou me deparando com constraints agora, e gostaria de saber como usar esta ferramenta corretamente. Se souber de um bom tutorial em inglês, ou português fico grato!

Comment: *Constraints* é um assunto bem amplo e complexo, [aqui](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) tem um ponta-pé inicial para entender o assunto. Mas se houver algum problema específico, talvez possa facilitar. Por exemplo, mostre algo que você já tenha feito com essa imagem e label, algum print ou similar.